# rake db:migrate task won't decrypt database.yml

Tags: ruby, encryption, yaml, rake, rake-task

### How can I get `rake db:migrate` to decrypt the encrypted database password created by the **[secure_yaml](https://github.com/huwtl/secure_yaml)** gem?

I am using the **[secure_yaml](https://github.com/huwtl/secure_yaml)** gem to encrypt the password of my database stored in the `database.yml`.

The YAML file looks something like this ***after*** encryption:

```
development:
   adapter: oracle_enhanced
   database: db_name
   username: username
   password: ENC(yCuO9BOKb3pa2SoiFq+B6A==)
```

I try using the task `rake db:migrate` to migrate the db, but for some reason, the rake task can't decrypt the **[secure_yaml](https://github.com/huwtl/secure_yaml)** encryption.

I end up getting the error:

> ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password

And I guess the reason is because the rake task reads the encrypted database password as a plain string.

### If its not possible,
what is a better way to encrypt the database password in the YAML file?

Comment: Do you provide `PROPERTIES_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD` as an environment variable like described in the docs? Btw why don't you use the [encryted credentials](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#environmental-security) that are coming with Rails?

Comment: I do provide it but somehow the migrate task wont recognise it. Do you know of any good way to assign environment variables maybe? I currenty use the dotenv gem for environments but am not sure whether or not it passes it over to the migrate rake task. Also I dont seem to understand how the encrypted credentials from Rails is meant to work. It doesnt say what to do and how. I really appreciate the reply @spickermann